# I have a Windows 10 Laptop, It doesn't boot up when I enable the HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bsod

I have a **Windows 10** laptop and I just upgraded it to use a **SSD** by replacing the old **HDD** with the new **SSD** and cloning the Windows with ***MiniTool***.

It was just working fine until I started having random **BSODs**, i just ignored all of that for the time being and thought that I would fix it later someday until one day I just boot up my laptop and it just got stuck on the company logo screen with `Preparing repairing options`.

Then I disabled the **HDD** and I boot up, than again when I enabled the **HDD**, it stopped booting with the same logo stuck problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: I understand that the computer can't boot with the HDD connected. It might be that the disk has died. Can it be connected after the boot? If yes, can you include its SMART values in your post?

Comment: Did you remove the HDD after cloning it to the SSD, or is the HDD still in the computer as a secondary drive? It's entirely likely that your HDD still has the boot sectors on it, and this is the drive your system is ACTUALLY using to initiate the boot process in your computer. There are several other questions on this site about moving the boot sectors when you migrate drives.

Comment: @music2myear The HDD is still inside my laptop as I cannot disassemble it myself an I did not format or clear the HDD. I just gave the SSD the boot order priority in the BIOS.

Comment: @harrymc As I stated in the question, It is not a desktop computer in which I am having this problem, It's a Laptop and I don't have much skill in disassembling a laptop so I can't just take out the HDD and boot up my Laptop and reconnect it :(

Comment: I meant : Can you disable the HDD, reboot, then enable it without Windows falling over? If yes, does it show up in Disk Management and can you read its SMART attributes? (If you don't have an app for that use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).)

Comment: @harrymc How do I enable the HDD after booting up? Because when I disable it in the BIOS, It won't show in the disk manager either....

Comment: You have the problem of the chicken and the egg... Try to enable the disk in the BIOS and boot with boot media, Linux if you know it, or Windows boot to command-line.